# Typescript: type checking middleware

Tags: typescript

I am trying to construct type safe middleware solution for (not only) AWS Lambda. Solution would allow for typical middleware actions: modify input, modify output, catch errors. On top of that it would provide static typing for values passed:

```
middleware(
 modifyInput(),
 modifyOutput(),
 handler,
);
```

`handler` requires input from `modifyInput()`, so that compilation would fail without `modifyInput()`. `modifyOutput()` requires output from `handler` so that compilation would fail without `handler`.

I have prepared a simplified example on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=93&ssc=49&pln=43&pc=1#code/PTAEGJNBJBZAFAMgUVsgcgFQIKegeXQkgCgSBTADwAcB7AJwBdQBLAO0fPoDMBDAY3KhYLACaiANuQDuveuQBiAVzb9GLWmwA8eNgBpQu2LVEHM+JYzMXGx0QD5QAbxKhQACnbVLALkPR9UDYqRj8RcSlZeXQQnQC7a0t7AEo-c0s7AG4SAF8yKjomVg4uPkFhMUkZOXIYykY4wPTGRxc3TzZvUP82VMMbbLyKGgZmbhU1DTZQAFtKyJqdAEYzACYzAGYzABYzAFYzADZ7d1dQbjYlsPnq+WVVdU1ltc2d+z0zi9XriNvFCce2kw60MB0Mh027xIfXCVSi-weU2eoKOb2yw0KYwBU1mN3hpzcADpiRcAM5+dywhZ3bFPXhsACeBnpTNALOZjMcAB8Kr94XUGuy2ZzkgBtAC60J+cJq90mdMZHNZQpZrTO8kYSno0zmfNl9FoM2w9HovAZ7jJyUGZHGiM0uL1dwNRpNZsaZniJkSVn6GRMJ0+bHJvJlNLtQICHrYCV9PuadnsEo+MLxstpEaantMse9CecZxY3A8ZMJUjYAHNGAALUAAXnroAADMl8243BqtdM2LRaNQqX82aSQ9SEfLtCrFcLlZzsm4hm5C8Wg6XyBXq3WG0sW202x3tecg6LG+LZ6B56A99MS-JREpBAAlFjlquMAlt9zyUlKCTdfvwuWAloE7TiB7wHtKI4AUiwFKkqKR1o4HRdAYwT1C2tb2GcbYHkhlgGO4qGMAEXToY4n7fq+hHEXhQQhMkyQfG4Vq5PkIxFPwmiksw3a9n+NR1qA7qxicXi+D0KEhBSVGdGJuikbG8mEbhjDMSQIDEOAoDIAAGtgCAoBpZCMAy1BCAoPbUcwtatqAXFyN0XH0Ow5aDNkxmmaA5m0JZdgCTu3A9n4jnOa5JDuWZPY2F0flnKuohBYwTkVqF4WeZFlhdL51n+YFtmJSFuTZLaY7nD2jTRSEcVDl5lnehV9RVWltBRUk7gpo6o6AWcujId1lmgAAZE1Plet1LVWGNGWWINTXjXYJBqu25CavuykSWhCE2W4HFBswtBTVZtH1O4TigMShKiT6AW0H4ADk123WeqnYZezhncS+2MMhpU3aA909o9OSnkDLFhSZQgAEJyP12VnHZTAJUlLmFWDHlQ-QI2iDFbgAEZyIjBUg6l6PjdjoBxQTyUo8TchzSYZN4-QlPIyDxWAqAjPldNlVsKIQ7o7Vsb1ZwvP87TB0nO1oadUifUyRNbg9dNQ0C-LCSTV9eEa9FKvi5rtgmAtNmvWtR0qZtO7bZxe0HQJSmnedl0GIzd2M4Dz27stnZvedn3fS7f1u2ewPWiQO1caAHEzDj7DkKIXnowJurSxaPZtc7chtcxQA) that illustrate the issue. `combinedFooBar` has a type of `MiddlewareFunction<never, never, never, never>` where I would expect roughly:

```
MiddlewareFunction<
  FooInput,
  FooInput & FooInputMod & BarInput & BarInputMod,
  BarOutput,
  BarOutput & BarOutputMod & FooOutput & FooOutputMod
>
```

[image: middleware representation]

Is there something I am doing wrong? Is it even possible? The idea for typing came from [RxJs implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/76731a9a0d8793918de9e662698f091f3868845b/src/internal/util/pipe.ts#L4-L16).